# Is there another different way of printing a cartesian product in a dictionary which has arrays as values following an specific order on Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, permutation, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 
                       'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 
                       'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 
                       'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 
                       'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 
                       'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

A way of printing each possible combination is by using `itertools`, here:

```
import itertools as it

AllKeysNames = the_dictionary_list.keys()
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```

This will print a `list` which has `360` elements in total.

However, let's say that the order matters in the previous case (i.e. permutations are needed), this order would be the following:

```
'Fondo'>'Cuerpo'>'Ojos'>'Color'>'Pinzas'>'Puas'
```

How could I make a program that always start with the value of '**Fondo**' key, then adds the value of '**Cuerpo**' key, then adds the first value of '**Color**' key, then adds the first value of '**Pinzas**' key, then adds the first value of '**Puas**' key and so on...?

In the end the total amount of elements in the new list would still be `360`, but this time these elements would have been created following an specific order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I even decided to let the user be the one who decides the order in which the permutations will be made.

```
# creating an empty list
Keys_input = []
# number of elements
n = len(the_dictionary_list)
i = 0
while True:
    AllKeysNames = the_dictionary_list.keys()
    print('\033[46m'+str(AllKeysNames)+'\033[0m')
    ele = input("\033[0;37;40mTell me which valid key you want me to set now:\033[0m ")
    if ele in the_dictionary_list and ele not in Keys_input:
        Keys_input.append(ele) # adding the element
        i += 1
        print(f'\033[0;37;42mThe array has been updated, its current storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
        if i == n:
            print("\u001b[45mThe array is now full, let's continue with the next step\033[0m")
            break
    else:
        if ele not in the_dictionary_list:
            print('\u001b[43mPlease, type only valid key names\033[0m')
        if ele in Keys_input:
            print('\u001b[43mStop, that key IS ALREADY SAVED in the array, try with a different valid one\033[0m')
            print(f'\u001b[45mCurrent storage of the array is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')     
AllKeysNames2 = Keys_input
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames2)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```